# How can changes be *ahead* of HEAD?

Tags: git

I have a number of changes that just, poof, disappeared from the tree.  Or they seem to be hovering just above the tree somehow...

For example, I had a file `scripts/skin.prestitial.supp.js` that I made a small change to, the commit was e48c156.

```
 git log scripts/skin.prestitial.supp.js
```

gives me

```
 commit bdf9ceda54e0cfc528f0618c6d47c0399cf956b0
 Author: David <david@company.com>
 Date:   Wed Feb 1 18:16:56 2012 -0800

     SV-865 - chat change prestitial

 commit f218dd99c42aeaa754a14644c951adde41a0b58c
 Author: David <david@company.com>
 Date:   Mon Jan 30 18:43:19 2012 -0800

     sv-753 how this works lb
```

and so on, without e48c156.  It had disappeared completely.  I'm like "Oh noes!", then I tried this:

```
 git log e48c156 scripts/skin.prestitial.supp.js
```

gives

```
 commit e48c1569f05481e269d7bfcd73547b2ec226e777
 Author: Michael <info@company.com>
 Date:   Wed Feb 1 19:50:48 2012 -0800

     SV-861  Add "Done" to "how it works" lightbox

 commit bdf9ceda54e0cfc528f0618c6d47c0399cf956b0
 Author: David <david@company.com>
 Date:   Wed Feb 1 18:16:56 2012 -0800

     SV-865 - chat change prestitial

 commit f218dd99c42aeaa754a14644c951adde41a0b58c
 Author: David <david@company.com>
 Date:   Mon Jan 30 18:43:19 2012 -0800

     sv-753 how this works lb
```

That is, the change was "above" or "after" the current HEAD. How did I do this?  How do I find all the other changes that are forward of "now"?  How do I get them back?  How do I keep this from happening again?

Comment: I have no idea how you did this, you'd have to look at your history, but it's fairly common to have commits that are "ahead" of `HEAD`. Simply doing `git reset --hard HEAD^` will back up `HEAD` by 1 commit, leaving your previous commit as "ahead" of `HEAD`.

Comment: Nope, nothing in my history like that.  The only unusual things were cherry-picks, but other than that, the usual run of `commit`, `push`, and `pull`.  How do I fix it though?

Comment: In this particular case? You could just `git reset --hard e48c156` if it really is directly after `HEAD`, or you could `cherry-pick` it, or `merge` it, or whatever. In the general case? You haven't shown any reason to believe there are any other commits that have been "lost" like this. And you *must* have done something to "lose" this commit.

Comment: Nope, there are about a dozen lost commits that I'm tracking down.

Comment: It sounds like you have some step in your workflow that's actually backing out of commits unintentionally. None of `commit`, `push`, or `pull` can do that. You must be running some other command.

Comment: @Malvolio: Kevin is entirely correct here. You did at least one other thing, and that was your problem. I've tried to mention a lot of the possibilities in my answer.

Comment: (1) You haven't "lost" anything, if it has a commit reference you can get back to it. Try `git checkout <the "missing" commit's hash>`. (2) Once you get this worked out, you should probably examine your git workflow to see why you're continually losing something. I would imagine that you're probably doing something wrong, repeatedly.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, please stop blaming Git. No matter what you think, you did something to cause that commit to no longer be reachable from HEAD, and to suggest that it was something that was out of your control can only keep you from figuring out what it was, how to fix it, and how to avoid it.

It could've been any number of things: resetting to a previous commit (`git reset`), checking out a previous commit or a branch at a previous commit (`git checkout`), doing a rebase and removing a commit (`git rebase -i`), amending a commit with something different (`git commit --amend`)...

Note that since your question is so vague, there are a ton of possibilities, and I've tried to cover all of the likely ones I've thought of, but I won't necessarily have thought of everything. Please don't blindly follow instructions if you don't understand them, or haven't verified that they're the right thing to do. (Your question doesn't, for example, actually demonstrate that you have commits *ahead* of HEAD; they could be diverged from it.)

There are two things you may want to do: see how the current position of HEAD relates to where you think it should be, and see how you moved it.

To see the current state of history, there are a few helpful things:

- See if you're on the branch you think you should be, by running `git branch` or even `git status`. If you simply had the wrong branch checked out, you might be done now - just check out the right thing. If you have detached your HEAD (i.e. don't have a branch checked out) you'll want to check out the right branch, and then if you'd made commits while HEAD was detached, merge those commits.
- View the history, preferably using `gitk --branches e48c156`, which ensures that it shows all branches and the commit you care about. You could also use `git log [--decorate] [--graph] ...` if you're more comfortable with it, but `gitk` is more adept at visually displaying large amounts of complex history.

You should be able to see how your currently checked out branch/commit relates to where you think you should be.

To see what you did to mess yourself up, the most helpful tool will be `git reflog`. This lists the previous positions of `HEAD`. It will list, in reverse chronological order, all previous positions of HEAD, along with a summary of the operations that caused each move. Possibly in combination with `gitk` for seeing where the commits are, you should be able to track down what you did. (You can also use it on a branch, with `git reflog show <branch>`.)  If the actual commit you want is one *past* e48c156, this would be the way to discover it.

When you find where you expect yourself to be, you can get yourself back to it. In most cases, this is as simple as `git merge <desired-commit>`. If you haven't made commits since you moved back, it'll be a fast-forward merge, which just moves you forward, and if you have, it'll be a nontrivial merge which ought to get you what you want. If you have local modifications you may need to stash them first. However, if the problem is that you did a rebase or perhaps amended a commit, and removed the one you want, you'll need to be more careful - most likely create a branch where things were before the mistake, and merge/rebase/cherry-pick in changes that were made after that.

As a last resort, there's also `git fsck`, which will print a list of all objects which are unreachable from your current refs. You'll want to look for dangling commits; you can then use whatever tools you're most comfortable with to determine if they're things you care about. But this shouldn't be necessary; the worst case is that things are in the reflogs.

As for how to avoid this happening again, well, figure out what you did wrong, and don't do it again. If it's something involving checking out the wrong thing, you could consider modifying your prompt to include the current branch name (and other helpful things):

```
export PS1="...$(__git_ps1 "(%s)")..."
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you did this (although a simple `git reset --hard HEAD~1` would produce the same behaviour).

Unlike other distributed version control systems like Mercurial, Git works on the principle of removing the links to your commits, not the commits themselves. (Much like deleting files.)

You may find `git fsck --lost-found` useful for finding other dangling commits.

Comment: I *never* do resets if I can avoid them and haven't done so in months.  The --lost-found 15 commits I have to track down.  If they are also in this Bermuda Triangle, is there a better way to pull them out then cherry-picking?

Comment: Dangling commits aren't necessarily missing commits. For example, if you run `git commit --amend`, you've now replaced the current commit with a new version, which makes the old commit dangling, but also useless.

Comment: You could just directly merge those commits into your current branch, or alternately create a new branch for each of them, rebase them, then merge in the order that works best for you. As @kevin-ballard points out, you may not want them and you should check them first with `git log` or `git diff` before merging or rebasing.

Comment: @tjdett: or `git show`, which shows the commit + a diff against its parent.

Answer (score 0):

This may be too obvious to be correct, but are you sure you didn't just accidentally checkout the previous commit? From your history, it looks like you committed, then changed your index to represent the previous head:

```
(previous commits) <-- f218dd9 <-- bdf9ced <-- e48c1569
                                      ^--you
```

Simply running a `git branch` or `git status` should tell you what branch and what commit you're working with, and `git log` should tell you where you are in the history of things. Consider making a new branch from your current location - `git checkout -b new branch HEAD` - and then switching to the top of `master` and seeing what it looks like.